# Calculate % of total - redshift / sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, percentage

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of one column over a secondary total column.

I wrote:

```
create temporary table screenings_count_2018 as

select guid,
       datepart(y, screening_screen_date)                          as year,
       sum(case when screening_package = 4 then 1 end)             as count_package_4,
       sum(case when screening_package = 3 then 1 end)             as count_package_3,
       sum(case when screening_package = 2 then 1 end)             as count_package_2,
       sum(case when screening_package = 1 then 1 end)             as count_package_1,
       sum(case when screening_package in (1, 2, 3, 4) then 1 end) as count_total_packages


from prod.leasing_fact

where year = 2018
group by guid, year;
```

That table establishes the initial count and total count columns. All columns look correct.

Then, I'm using ratio_to_report to calculate the percentage (referencing [this](http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-percentage-total.html) tutorial):

```
create temporary table screenings_percentage as

    select
    guid,
    year,
    ratio_to_report(count_package_1) over (partition by count_total_packages) as percentage_package_1

from screenings_count_2018

group by guid, year,count_package_1,count_total_packages
order by percentage_package_1 desc;
```

I also tried:

```
select
    guid,
    year,
    sum(count_package_1/count_total_packages) as percentage_package_1

    -- ratio_to_report(count_package_1) over (partition by count_total_packages) as percentage_package_1

from screenings_count_2018

group by guid, year,count_package_1,count_total_packages
order by percentage_package_1 desc;
```

Unfortunately, percentage_package_1 just returns all null values (this is not correct - I'm expecting percentages). Neither are working.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already laid out the columns with components and a total, in creating `screenings_count_2018`, do you actually need to use `ratio_to_report`?

```
select
    , guid
    , year
    , count_package_1/count_total_packages as percentage_package_1
    , count_package_2/count_total_packages as percentage_package_2
    , count_package_3/count_total_packages as percentage_package_3
    , count_package_4/count_total_packages as percentage_package_4
from screenings_count_2018
```

That should work. NB are you guaranteed to never have `count_total_packages` be zero? If it can be zero you'll need to handle it. One way is with a case statement.

If you wish for the per-package percentages to appear in a single column, then you can use `ratio_to_report` -- it is a "window" analytic function and it will be something like this against the original table.

```
with count_table as (
select guid
       , datepart(y, screening_screen_date) as year
       , screening_package
       , count(1) as count
from prod.leasing_fact
where year = 2018
group by guid
    , datepart(y, screening_screen_date)
    , screening_package
)
select guid
    , year
    , screening_package
    , ratio_to_report(count) over(partition by guid, year, screening_package) as perc_of_total
from count_table
```

Answer (score 2):

you will need `round(100.0*count_package_1/count_total_packages,1)` and so on as you already calculated the subtotal and total